# How to play in the same web page MPG video/audio files without making another new tab or new browser window?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, dojo

I have 100 training, lecture, guide video files which has size 30MB to 1GB each of them. And they are all .mp4/mpg format. There is no web player i have found to play it in the inline html.

So this is what i am doing now let them download it. But i am looking for a way how to play those files using a web based media player so that the quality is not drop and it looks like same page without `target="_blank"`, but with iframe?

Current code is like this:

```
<a href="/1/720p.mpg" target="_blank"> 
  <img src="/img/icon/playivr.png" style="border:0px;"> 
</a>

<a href="/1/1080p.mpg" target="_blank"> 
  <img src="/img/icon/playivr.png" style="border:0px;"> 
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try use object tag for that:

```
<object data="data/test.mpg" type="video/mpeg" width="320" height="255">
  <param name="src" value="data/test.mpg">
  <param name="autoplay" value="false">
  <param name="autoStart" value="0">
  alt : <a href="data/test.mpg">test.mpg</a>
</object>
```

But this will work only if user have a plugin.

The better way would be to convert videos to flv format using ffmpeg for example and play using some flash-based player. It's better since flash in installed on about 99% of computers.

Comment: you are right. But the problem is it has to be in presentation replay where there is 40" LCD or 63 LCD" screen. When i do FLV conversion the quality drops and shows pixelation.

Comment: So i need to replay as it is with same format. The files are original camera source which was used to record it. Those camera's are very expensive camera's like STUDIO's.

Comment: The same file that is showing in the browser, also get sent/spred to other cluster nodes. Like Video WALL all need quality and same source of file.

Comment: @Google So if you will have control over the environment where your page will run you can try to use <object> or <video> to show video on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Google chrome latest version supports HTML 5 tag "VIDEO"

```
<video width="1024" height="768" controls="controls">
   <source src="file:HaveFun.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Latest firefox browser supports the "video" tag but is unable to play mp4 files.

Answer (score -1):

you can convert them to swf and run them as a flash or upload them to youtube then do the embedding thing. or be creative and use FLASH software and do your own player.

there is this Quick time thing but its isn't  nice at all